# Обновление PHP 5.5.9 до PHP 5.6 на Linux

Tags: php, linux

Выполнил команды:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip
sudo service apache2 restart
```

В консоли при выполнении `php -v` версия поменялась:

```
PHP 5.6.30-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

А в браузере `phpinfo()` выдаёт старую версию `5.5.9`.

Comment: В  перечисленном списке пакетов не вижу ни модуль апача ни fpm. Вы выдели в отчёте `apt-get`, что необходимый пакет подтянулся по зависимостям?

Comment: Вроде бы, нужен ещё пакет с именем типа `libapache2-mod-php5.6` или что-то вроде того.

Answer (score 2):

Приведите для ясности конфиги от apache, пожалуйста. Я предположу, что у вас используется **mod_php** для подключения php к apache.

Вы не установили модуль для apache2. Apache все еще использует старую версию mod_php.

Установите **libapache2-mod-php5.6** (из того же репозитория, что и php5.6), но сначала удалите или выключите старую версию.

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6
sudo a2enmod php5.6
```

Установка PHP из данного репозитория не обновляет уже существующий PHP, поэтому нужно вручную удалить php5 из системы. Конфиги старого php находятся в /etc/php5, поэтому все, что нужно из php.ini нужно перенести в /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini.

Есть также возможность использовать php5.6-fpm, что в общем-то и рекомендуется, поскольку это даст возможность использовать несколько версий php на одной системе (5.6 и 7.0, например).